# Can I set custom from for mails JavaMailSenderImpl

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jakarta-mail

I use JavaMailSenderImpl in my web-app (Spring MVC). I send mails from some acc, for example "sender@gmail.com". I need setFrom to another acc , for example "sender2@gmail.com". How I can do it? I try `setFrom("sender2@gmail.com")`, but users receives mails with From: "sender@gmail.com". What am I doing wrong?
My config:

```
public JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender() {
    JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSenderImpl = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
    try {
        javaMailSenderImpl.setHost("smtp.gmail.com");
        javaMailSenderImpl.setPort(567);
        javaMailSenderImpl.setUsername("sender@gmail.ua");
        javaMailSenderImpl.setPassword("*********");
        javaMailSenderImpl.getJavaMailProperties().put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        javaMailSenderImpl.getJavaMailProperties().put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        javaMailSenderImpl.getJavaMailProperties().put("mail.debug", "true");
        javaMailSenderImpl.getJavaMailProperties().put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        javaMailSenderImpl.getJavaMailProperties().put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        javaMailSenderImpl.getJavaMailProperties().setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        javaMailSenderImpl.getJavaMailProperties().setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        javaMailSenderImpl.getJavaMailProperties().setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
    }
    return javaMailSenderImpl;
}
```

And my code for send emails:

```
MimeMessage message2 = javaMailSenderImpl.createMimeMessage();
        Address  from = new InternetAddress("sender2@gmail.com");
        message2.setFrom(from);
        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message2, true);
        helper.setFrom("sender2@gmail.com");
/*adding body,subject etc*/
 javaMailSenderImpl.send(message2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You use authentication.

I think to edit some code.

sample.

(pom.xml)

```
<!-- java mail api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
</dependency>

<!-- send mail -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.7</version>
</dependency>
```

(test mian class)

```
public class MyAuthentication extends Authenticator {

    PasswordAuthentication pa;

    private final static String id = "test@gmail.com";
    private final static String pw = "1234";

    public MyAuthentication() {
        pa = new PasswordAuthentication(id, pw);
    }

    // authentication
    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return pa;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties p = System.getProperties();
        p.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        p.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        p.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        p.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        Authenticator auth = new MyAuthentication();
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(p, auth);
        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

        try {

            msg.setSentDate(new Date());
            InternetAddress from = new InternetAddress();
            from = new InternetAddress("test<" + id + ">");

            // sender
            msg.setFrom(from);

            // receiver
            InternetAddress to = new InternetAddress("test123@gmail.com");
            msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, to);

            // title
            msg.setSubject("test send email", "UTF-8");

            // context
            msg.setText("context bla~bla~", "UTF-8");

            // header
            msg.setHeader("content-Type", "text/html");

            // send msg
            javax.mail.Transport.send(msg);
            System.out.println("send email");

        } catch (AddressException addr_e) {
            addr_e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MessagingException msg_e) {
            msg_e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See this Gmail help page about [sending mail from a different address or alias](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en).